# Json combine two files for a large value

Tags: c#, json

Here are two json samples.

I want to combine this json into a file.
If a key exists in a value that is combined without thinking, it is difficult to replace only the value that is high in value.

First Sample.

```
 {
      "employees": [
        {
          "firstName": "Tom",
          "HighValue": "3"
        },
        {
          "firstName": "Maria",
          "HighValue": "4"
        },
        {
          "firstName": "Robert",
          "HighValue": "45"
        }
      ]
 }
```

Second Sample.

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "firstName": "Tom",
      "HighValue": "6"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Maria",
      "HighValue": "4"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Robert",
      "HighValue": "45"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "John",
      "HighValue": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want Result:

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "firstName": "Tom",
      "HighValue": "6"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Maria",
      "HighValue": "4"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Robert",
      "HighValue": "45"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "John",
      "HighValue": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

The goal is to combine two samples, Json, into one result json. What's the best way?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Include your code.

Comment: Have you tried Newtonsoft.Json yet? It has a lot of useful tools to accomplish what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe you could: Read all the content of each file and put then into strings. Use these strings to deserialize json into objects with a lib called Newtonsoft.Json. Manipulate these objects as you want and serialize to json again.

Comment: You can deserialize the files, then do the operations that you want

Comment: @FelipeOriani, why reading the files into strings and then deserializing the strings, instead of letting the deserializer just deserialize the JSON from the files directly?

Comment: @elgonzo post a solution.

Comment: @FelipeOriani, What o_O? How is your comment as a response to my comment - which itself was a response to your 1st comment - making any sense?

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach would be by making use of a json framework like [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) which handles serialization/deserialization for you.
First create a data model into which your json data can be deserialized to. I used the online tool [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) for this. This will give you the following model:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public int HighValue { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Employee> employees { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can simply deserialize your json strings into objects like this:

```
string json1 = "";
string json2 = "";

var obj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json1);
var obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json2);
```

After this step you just have to iterate over your employees, check if they exist in both lists and add/update them accordingly:

```
foreach(var emp in obj2.employees)
{
    Employee existing = null;
    try
    {
        existing = obj1.employees.SingleOrDefault(e => e.firstName == emp.firstName);
    } 
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // The same employee exists multiple times in the first list
    }

    if(existing != null)
    {
        // obj1 already contains an employee with the given name, check which value is bigger
        if(existing.HighValue < emp.HighValue)
        {
            // The value of the existing employee is smaller 
            // -> Update the value with the value from the second object
            existing.HighValue = emp.HighValue;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // obj1 does not already contain an employee with the given name, add the whole employee
        obj1.employees.Add(emp);
    }
}
```

Now `obj1` contains the combined list of employees.
To serialize the combined list back to json do the following:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj1);
```

Answer (score 0):

(For the record JSON isn't one of my strongest points but I thought answering this for you would be a good challenge)

The following code takes both JSON samples as JObjects using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/), then merges the two samples together. I then use LINQ to group and select the people with the highest values and output a new array.

The advantage to this solution is if you only want to use C# to merge, not use it for any other logic, you don't need to deserialize to an object.
Give it a try:

```cs
var firstSample = JObject.Parse("Your first sample goes here");
var secondSample = JObject.Parse("Your second sample goes here");
var newJsonArray = new JArray(); //Makes new array for output

firstSample.Merge(secondSample); //Merges the firstSample JObject with secondSample JObject
var filteredJson = firstSample["employees"] //Makes new JObject with filtered values
    .GroupBy(x => x["firstName"]) // Groups by the first name
    .Select(x => x.Where(y => y["HighValue"] == x.Max(z => z["HighValue"]))) // Select the employee in each group with the highest value
    .ToList(); // Converts to a list out

foreach (var token in filteredJson)
{
    newJsonArray.Add(token); // For each selected employee, add it to the new array
}

var outputJson = new JObject(new JProperty("employees", newJsonArray)); // Composes the new JSon string
```